# Deserialization of Binary Objects

Tags: .net

I'm building a data logger which receives data through a serial port through byte frames of variable size which are produced by the device using some kind of serialization. My goal is to deserialize this frame as fast as possible (the device publishes a frame of 400...500 bytes every 50 milliseconds.

Frame structure looks like that. It is much more complex actually!

- Byte   Variable
- 00     Value1
- 01     Value2
- 02     Value3
- 03     N of iterations of Value4 (Example=3) - Maximum 10
- 04     Value4 Iteration 1
- 05     Value4 Iteration 2
- 06     Value4 Iteration 3
- 07     Value5
- 08     Value6

Currently, i'm normalizing the frame: in the example above, if N of iterations of Value 4 is 1, i'll add 9 fake bytes (using List.InsertRange) after the 1st iteration of value 4, so i can always get Value 5 & 6 at the same, fixed position.

Due to the complexity of the frame, i have to call .InsertRange about 10...20x times at every frame (every 50ms), so performance is really bad.

Is there some special method to de-serialize such objects, which is more efficient?
PS: This is my first question on StackOverflow.. Hope it's clear enough :)

Comment: you'll need to post some relevant code.

Comment: For this kind of low-level code working with intensive IO, I suspect that you don't want to be using `List<>`, though it may be possible to use it more efficiently than you are (avoiding multiple array allocations, for example).  Ultimately, though, if your algorithm calls for shifting data around an array ten to twenty times, it may be better to write a custom algorithm that deals directly with the array and shifts each byte once rather than using InsertRange.  I agree with Jeremy that it's not really possible to offer a good answer without some sample code.